# How to find maximum overlap between two strings in Scala?

Tags: string, scala

Suppose I have two strings: `s` and `t`. I need to write a function `f` to find a max. `t` prefix, which is also an `s` suffix. For example:

```
 s = "abcxyz", t = "xyz123", f(s, t) = "xyz"
 s = "abcxxx", t = "xx1234", f(s, t) = "xx"
```

How would you write it in Scala ?

Comment: If you search for Longest common substring problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) implementation, you might find one for the JVM, which you can use from Scala.

Comment: @GáborBakos LCS looks like another more difficult problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the prefix/suffix restriction.

Comment: For s = "abcxyz", t = "5yz123", is f(s, t) = "yz" ok ?

Comment: @enzyme No. "yz" is not a _prefix_ of `t`.

Comment: What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: @Ashalynd Your solution is fine. Thank you very much for your help! I've upvoted it. I don't know how it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This first solution is easily the most concise, also it's more efficient than a recursive version as it's using a lazily evaluated iteration

```
s.tails.find(t.startsWith).get
```

Now there has been some discussion regarding whether `tails` would end up copying the whole string over and over.  In which case you could use `toList` on `s` then `mkString` the result.

```
s.toList.tails.find(t.startsWith(_: List[Char])).get.mkString
```

For some reason the type annotation is required to get it to compile.  I've not actually trying seeing which one is faster.

**UPDATE - OPTIMIZATION**

As som-snytt pointed out, `t` cannot start with any string that is longer than it, and therefore we could make the following optimization:

```
s.drop(s.length - t.length).tails.find(t.startsWith).get
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on Ashalynd's answer, using `prefix.substring(1)` is probably much more efficient than `prefix.drop(1)` for strings.

Comment: @DaoWen I've changed it to use `tail`, no idea why I left it as `drop(1)`

Comment: If s is long and t is short, it's not efficient, but should filter on the length condition.

Answer (score 3):

If we only need to find the common overlapping part, then we can recursively take tail of the first string (which should overlap with the beginning of the second string) until the remaining part will not be the one that second string begins with. This also covers the case when the strings have no overlap, because then the empty string will be returned.

```
scala> def findOverlap(s:String, t:String):String = { 
    if (s == t.take(s.size)) s else findOverlap (s.tail, t) 
}
findOverlap: (s: String, t: String)String

scala> findOverlap("abcxyz", "xyz123")
res3: String = xyz

scala> findOverlap("one","two")
res1: String = ""
```

UPDATE: It was pointed out that `tail` might not be implemented in the most efficient way (i.e. it creates a new string when it is called). If that becomes an issue, then using `substring(1)` instead of `tail` (or converting both Strings to Lists, where it's tail / head should have O(1) complexity) might give a better performance. And by the same token, we can replace `t.take(s.size)` with `t.substring(0,s.size)`.

Comment: I'd say it's quite inefficient to take `tail` in a recursive loop, since with current Java version this creates a completely new string. Of course, this is often irrelevant in practice, but it is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: tail is supposed to be O(1), at least for a List. Then it might make sense to convert this string into a List first.

Comment: Looks like a similar issue for StringOps(slice) was fixed a couple of years ago: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2895 if it was not done for drop, then perhaps using substring can be an option here too?

Comment: @Michael My idea was to add an extra parameter for size of checked string, starting with `min(s.size, t.size)` and decreasing, but actually I see I'll run into the same problem. If efficiency is _really_ required and the strings are really long, you could drop down to `char[]`, but this answer should actually be good enough.

Comment: @Ashalynd Actually, the issue I was thinking of is precisely that `substring` used to share the array used by the original string, but creates a new string starting with Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

Efficient, this is not, but it is a neat (IMO) one-liner.

```
val s = "abcxyz"
val t ="xyz123"

(s.tails.toSet intersect t.inits.toSet).maxBy(_.size)
 //res8: String = xyz
```

(take all the suffixes of s that are also prefixes of t, and pick the longest)

Comment: Nice, didn't know `tails` existed, used it in my answer :) Now I have a super concise one-liner: `s.tails.find(t.startsWith).get`

Comment: Yes, that's neat and reasonably efficient (since s.tails returns an iterator). I like the (near) symmetry of mine, though