# Find multiple overlaps between two strings in scala?

Tags: string, scala, overlap

Suppose I have the following strings :

```
my_str1 = "Some Text is here too"
my_str2 = "Text was present here too"
```

So the overlapping terms are `Text`,`here` and `too`.

I saw [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105054/how-to-find-maximum-overlap-between-two-strings-in-scala) and was wondering if it is possible to extend it to my problem with multiple overlaps ?

**EDIT : The strings may be continuous as well. Like this:**

```
my_str1 = "SomeTextisheretoo"
my_str2 = "Textwaspresentheretoo"
```

So in this case the output will be `Text` and `heretoo`.

Answer (score 3):

For your scenario, the `str` has the **space** between words, You can just use `intersect` to get the  overlapping terms, like:

```
val res1 = "Some Text is here too".split("\\s+")
val res2 = "Text was present here too".split("\\s+")

res1.intersect(res2)

> res: Array[String] = Array(Text, here, too)
```

Doc: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#intersect(that:Seq[A]):Array[A]

Comment: I am sorry I will update my question. The Strings may also be continuous.

Comment: for this scenario, you are trying to solve the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), but for your example, you are expecting multi common substring, but it's impossible to measure how long should a common term, if your problem is NLP topic, you maybe is trying to find a **tokenizer** for this and find the common terms.