# Walk me through the string overlap algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, scala

This is a followup to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61311799/521070)

I have a hard time understanding the code below.
I understand *what* the code does but I don't understand *why* we calculate `updatedOverlap` like this:

```
val currentOverlap = 
  Iterator.iterate(overlaps.last)(overlap => overlaps(overlap - 1))
    .find(overlap => overlap == 0 || hasPrefix.lift(overlap).contains(currentCharacter))
    .getOrElse(0)
val updatedOverlap = currentOverlap + if (hasPrefix.lift(overlap).contains(currentCharacter)) 1 else 0)
```

As I understand, `overlaps[i]` is the overlap between `hasSuffix[0...i - 1]` and `hasPrefix`. Thus `overlaps[hasSuffix.length]` is the sought overlap between `hasSuffix` and `hasPrefix`.

What I *don't* understand is the iteration `Iterator.iterate(overlaps.last)(overlap => overlaps(overlap - 1))`.
Why do we "jump" from `overlap` to `overlaps(overlap - 1)` ?

Comment: Hello, I've checked my original post, and, I'm sorrry, but it turns out my modification of the prefix function was completely wrong. This "jump" is unsound. Try e.g. `overlap("abfababa", "ababc")`, you'll get 1 instead of 3. But the approach using the standard prefix function to get `O(n+k)` time should still work. So try converting the algorithm from one of the links to Scala and run it: `prefix_function("ababc#abfababa")` and you'll get `pi.last == 3` as expected. I'll check if it's actually possible to write it without adding sentinel characters like `#`, and fix my old answer later.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot ! I am sure some `O(n+k)` should exist. I will try also the sentinel approach you suggested.